# Implement vue draggable in a table. Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to create a survey with the option to order the questions that are displayed in a table when creating the survey.

I'm using [vue draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) and the example works but I don't know how to use this with a table and still get the rows to be draggable

Example

```
<draggable v-model="section" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false">
    <div v-for="section in surveySections" :key="section.id">{{section.title}}</div
</draggable>
```

This is the table

```
<el-table
    :data="form.question_id"
        border>
    <draggable v-model="surveyQuestions" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false">
        <el-table-column prop="title" label="Pregunta"></el-table-column>
                <el-col :xs="5">
                <el-table-column fixed="right" label="Operaciones">
                <template slot-scope="scope">
                    <el-button
                        @click.native.prevent="deleteRow(scope.$index, form.question_id)"
                        type="text" size="small">
                        <span class="icon-create">Eliminar</span>
                        <i class="el-icon-delete-solid"></i>
                    </el-button>
                </template>
            </el-table-column>
        </el-col>
    </draggable>
</el-table>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Could the engine run only the columns?
Like this example:https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/table-column-example, please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290034/how-to-move-columns-from-the-table-column-elerment-ui-and-vuedraggable

Comment: Please partner, can you support me. I need to drag the columns.

Comment: @JG_GJ are you using Element-ui table?

Comment: now i have changed everything to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/xmwh/2t3zbhkx/
It has worked for me in 90%, I only have the problem that the header does not change it, the other rows do, only the header does not change it, I don't know if it is because I get my data from the server Please if you could help me, thank you very much and i'm using data-tables-server https://www.njleonzhang.com/vue-data-tables/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/en-us/basic?id=render-and-refresh-the-table

Comment: Why would the header change on the table? I'm not sure what you mean when you say this is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I must have 50 reputation to comment！
SO.

you can see [elementUI Table组件实现拖拽效果](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_26440803/article/details/83663511)

e.g

```js
npm install sortablejs --save

// Element table must specify row-key . Otherwise, the order will be wrong

import Sortable from 'sortablejs'


<template>
  <div style="width:800px">

    <el-table :data="tableData"
      border
      row-key="id"
      align="left">
     <el-table-column v-for="(item, index) in col"
        :key="`col_${index}`"
        :prop="dropCol[index].prop"
        :label="item.label"> 
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
    <pre style="text-align: left">
      {{dropCol}}
    </pre>
    <hr>
    <pre style="text-align: left">
      {{tableData}}
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Sortable from 'sortablejs'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      col: [
        {
          label: '日期',
          prop: 'date'
        },
        {
          label: '姓名',
          prop: 'name'
        },
        {
          label: '地址',
          prop: 'address'
        }
      ],
      dropCol: [
        {
          label: '日期',
          prop: 'date'
        },
        {
          label: '姓名',
          prop: 'name'
        },
        {
          label: '地址',
          prop: 'address'
        }
      ],
      tableData: [
        {
          id: '1',
          date: '2016-05-02',
          name: '王小虎1',
          address: '上海市普陀区金沙江路 100 弄'
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: '王小虎2',
          address: '上海市普陀区金沙江路 200 弄'
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          date: '2016-05-01',
          name: '王小虎3',
          address: '上海市普陀区金沙江路 300 弄'
        },
        {
          id: '4',
          date: '2016-05-03',
          name: '王小虎4',
          address: '上海市普陀区金沙江路 400 弄'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.rowDrop()
    this.columnDrop()
  },
  methods: {
    //行拖拽
    rowDrop() {
      const tbody = document.querySelector('.el-table__body-wrapper tbody')
      const _this = this
      Sortable.create(tbody, {
        onEnd({ newIndex, oldIndex }) {
          const currRow = _this.tableData.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]
          _this.tableData.splice(newIndex, 0, currRow)
        }
      })
    },
    //列拖拽
    columnDrop() {
      const wrapperTr = document.querySelector('.el-table__header-wrapper tr')
      this.sortable = Sortable.create(wrapperTr, {
        animation: 180,
        delay: 0,
        onEnd: evt => {
          const oldItem = this.dropCol[evt.oldIndex]
          this.dropCol.splice(evt.oldIndex, 1)
          this.dropCol.splice(evt.newIndex, 0, oldItem)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

[element ui table Sortable.js](https://blog.csdn.net/liub37/article/details/82719211)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I ended up using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-ui-el-table-draggable

Comment: Companion I have implemented it and it has worked for me, but when I do it with data returned by the server, it does not work as expected, the only problem is that the header does not change, but the other fields do. I am using data-tables-server